# Angular multiple *ngFor and their relationships

Tags: json, angular

I was working to generate a pivot table using two jsons array. so i need to generate column dynamically also inject/find the key dynamically. so my first json array's key depends on second array. i hope you'll get clear understanding if you see my below code snippets. i can do it using external function but i need simple way.

```
<tr *ngFor="let x of btsTable;">
    <td>{{x.MCC}}</td>
    <td>{{x.LAC}}</td>
    <td>{{x.CID}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let col of columns;"> {{x.col}}</td> //col as key for x
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use square brackets to access the property. `x[col]`

```
<td *ngFor="let col of columns;"> {{x[col]}}</td> //col as key will inject for x
```

Comment: Wonderful job Sachila

Comment: What is the real problem for OP? What is the difference between your answer and OP question.

Comment: Op trying to access the array property using a variable.